# How to use foreach loop on a QSignalSpy

Tags: c++, qt, foreach, qt4, qtestlib

How do I use a `foreach` loop on a `QSignalSpy`?

This is what I want to do:

```
foreach( const QList<QVariant> &args, mySignalSpy )
{
    Q_ASSERT( args.count() == 2 );
    QVariant arg0 = args[0];
    QVariant arg1 = args[1];
    doSomething( arg0, arg1 );
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2-shared/include/QtTest/qsignalspy.h: In instantiation of ‘QForeachContainer<T>::QForeachContainer(const T&) [with T = QSignalSpy]’:
MyTester.cxx:843:64:   required from here
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2-shared/include/QtCore/qobject.h:333:5: error: ‘QObject::QObject(const QObject&)’ is private
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`foreach` makes a copy of passed container. `QSignalSpy` inherits `QObject` hence it cannot be copied. These two facts cause the error.

The simpliest workaround is to use usual `for` loop. You can also create a non-QObject copy of the list and use it to iterate:

```
QList< QList<QVariant> > list = mySignalSpy;
foreach( const QList<QVariant> &args, list ) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of why it fails as well as the workaround! +1